# error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make my first node.js web-app. But when I try to get the `localhost:3030` I get these errors in the console's chrome.

error 1:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "localhost:3030/vendor/jquery/jquery.js". localhost/:1

error 2:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:1

error 3:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) mvAuth.js:1

error 4:

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mvAuthProvider <- mvAuth
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=mvAuthProvider%20%3C-%20mvAuth
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3753:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3881:39)
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3758:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3881:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3908:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3928:23)
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:7216:28
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:6607:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:332:20) <div ng-include="'/partials/account/navbar-login'" class="ng-scope"> angular.js:9959
```

error 5:

```
ReferenceError: tue is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3030/app/main/mvMainCtrl.js:6:70)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3917:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:3928:23)
    at http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:7216:28
    at link (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js:913:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:6648:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:6039:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:5934:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:6059:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:6669:18) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"> angular.js:9959
```

How do I fix these, please ?

Comment: Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: post the code or give some link to code?